# Move 1000s of files on the go

Tags: windows, batch-file, cmd

I have more than 100 thousand of files in my local machine. 
filenames as `file1.txt, file2.txt to file99999.txt,` 
I want to move files of `file1.txt to file25000.txt` to some other location say Junks\file1.txt.

Please let me know how can we move files with regular expression using  cmd prompt or batch . Any help will be highly appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

This should create a `Junks` folder in the current directory and move the files you have described to the `Junks` folder.

Remove `& echo file %%a` to speed it up but you will not see any screen output.

```
@echo off
MD "Junks" 2>nul
for /L %%a in (1,1,25000) do move "file%%a.txt" "Junks" >nul & echo file %%a
```